# What exposure would my CiviCRM campaign receive?

Tags: fundraising

I was preparing to create a GoFundMe page for an project at an orphanage my son runs in the Philippines, and someone suggested I use CiviCRM instead.  I am not at all familiar with CiviCRM (or any CRM site), but I am familiar with GFM.  Would CiviCRM be better in any way, and if so, how?  I know I can get a lot of exposure on GFM and it has several similar pages to what I would create that have been very successful at fundraising.  Can anyone sell me on using CiviCRM instead of GFM?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

GoFundMe and CiviCRM are very different things.  If you want to build your own fundraising platform like GFM you might start with CiviCRM but if your interest is just to raise funds for your son's orphanage then GFM or similar is a much easier route.

Answer (score 1):

Aidan is correct - but to add to that, GoFundMe is better for an organization that has a one-time need for fundraising, and CiviCRM is built to track and sustain ongoing relationships.  Most non-profits want to have an ongoing record of their interactions with donors, which GFM won't provide you.

However, a tool like CiviCRM is more aimed at professional fundraisers, and has a much higher learning curve than GFM.  If your son's organization has a person whose permanent job description involves fundraising, then CiviCRM is a tool to consider.  If not, GFM is probably a better choice.